# How to retrieve the data from localstorage in the order we set it

Tags: jquery, json, html, local-storage

I am tying read a json file by looping through the topmenu (array of objects) and get item out it and store it into localstorage. everything works fine and even the data gets stored in localstorage. But my problem is it stores the data in localStorage in a sorted order which might be its default behavior. But I dont need it in sorted order, I want it in the order which it is present in the json. Because when I store the data to localstorage and  read the data from localstorage it comes in the sorted order. I can use the key in the $.each and append it to maintain our order if it automatically sorts. But why is it sorting itself. Is there any other work-around. Please help me solving this.

**NOTE:**
***I need to store the data to localStorage from json. Then read it from localstorage and donot read the json till the localstorage is completely empty. When I manually change the values in localstorage it should reflect in the menu. I have done all the conditional coding just need to figure out the localstorage problem, which is storing it in sorting order.***

Below is my JSON file, javascript and partial html:
**JSON**

```
{
    "topmenu":
    [
        {
            "item": "File"
        },
        {
            "item": "Help"
        },
        {
            "item": "Edit"
        },
        {
            "item": "View"
        },
        {
            "item": "Go"
        },
        {
            "item": "Tools"
        },
        {
            "item": "Actions"
        }
    ]
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if (typeof localStorage === "undefined") {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
    }

    $.getJSON("header.json", function(data) {        
        $.each(data.topmenu, function(key, val) {
            localStorage.setItem(val.item, val.item);
        });
        loadMenu();
    });

    function loadMenu() {
        $('.horizontalmenu').html('');
        if (!localStorage.length < 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                var item = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
                $('.horizontalmenu').append('<li class="menu"><a href="#">' + item + '</a></li>');
            }
        } else {
            $('.horizontalmenu').html("<li class='menu'>No menu</li>");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**PARTIAL HTML**

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="header-title">
        Test
        </div>
        <div id="header-menu">
                <ul class="horizontalmenu">
                </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try concatenate a index + your key? Ex: 1_File; 2_Help. Or create another property in your json "position" and use underscore.js to retrieve in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the JSON itself. `localStorage` acts like an object which doesn't have order.

```
localStorage.setItem("menu_items", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then you can get the JSON and parse it using `JSON.parse()` method.

However, I'm not sure why are you are storing the items, why not passing the data to your `loadMenu` function?

```
loadMenu(data.topmenu);

function loadMenu(elems) {
    // var elems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("menu_items")).topmenu;
    $('.horizontalmenu').empty();
    if (elems.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            var item = elems[i].item;
            $('.horizontalmenu').append('<li class="menu"><a href="#">' + item + '</a></li>');
        }
    } else {
        $('.horizontalmenu').html("<li class='menu'>No menu</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: actually requirement is that way. We need to store the data to localStorage from json. Then read it from localstorage and dont read the json till the localstorage is completely empty. and when we change the the values manually in localstorage it should reflect in the menu. I have done all the conditional coding just need to figure out the localstorage problem. which sorts by itself

Comment: @susheel As I have mentioned in the answer, `localStorage` items don't preserve the order (_just like an object's properties_), you should store an array-like item for this.  That's why I have suggested storing the JSON as it contains an ordered collection (ie, an array.)

Comment: But I dont see the content retrieval from localStorage in your code ?? your code directly reads the json and displays adds it to the menu

Comment: @susheel Actually there is, have you seen the commented line?

Comment: you commented so I ignored it. Let me try that

Comment: I got idea after seeing your code and written a code which suits my requirement. I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

At last got an idea from answer by user **@BlackSheep** and posting my solution based on it.Let me even explain the behaviour of the code:

My code actually checks if the localstorage is empty or if its not empty then it checks if its value(localStorage value which is json string) is equal to the actual json(converted to string). This check is made to make sure that, if new items are added to json file, it should even update it in the local storage. if both the condition fails it does nothing and keeps reading from the localStorage.

In load menu I am simply reading the value from local storage which is json string so converting it into and json object and parsing it to get the values. Looks complex but this is the requirement. I could have been directly done by parsing the json and displaying in menu.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if (typeof localStorage === "undefined") {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
    }

    $.getJSON("data/header.json", function(data) {
        if ((localStorage.length === 0) || (localStorage.getItem("menu_items") != JSON.stringify(data))) {
            localStorage.setItem("menu_items", JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        loadMenu();
    });

    function loadMenu() {
        $('.horizontalmenu').empty();
        if (!localStorage.length < 1) {            
                var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("menu_items"));
                $.each(item.topmenu,function(key,val){
                     $('.horizontalmenu').append('<li class="menu"><a href="#">' + val.item + '</a></li>');
                });               
        } else {
             $('.horizontalmenu').html("<li class='menu'>No menu</li>");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using val.item as both the key and the value?
How about a numeric index as the key?. Then retrieve by index in a for loop .

Comment: I have done that already it works. But why is local storage sorting itself is my question(may be it is inbuilt feature). just wanted to know if there a way so that we store it in the order we need with names not numbers. just to be clear what actually the particular item is: I can even do 1_file etc but that doesn't make sense and looks like dirty fix.

Comment: I see nothing in the spec about guaranteed order of items in local storage. Therefore this cannot be expected, which is why checking against an index or timestamp seems necessary.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have got another solution which I answered. you can have look at that :)

Comment: by the way, local storage its sorted alphabetically, at least in chrome.

Comment: yeah It does in chrome.