# localStorage in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following dynamic html

```
  $('#chat-box').html(                       
     '<p>Enter Your Name</p><input type="text" id="chat-box-name" class="chat-editing" />'
 );
```

Now i am storing value entered in above input box in `localStorage` like below

```
 namedata = $('#chat-box-name').val();
    localStorage.setItem('nams',namedata);
```

And then i am fetching it in other js file as follows:

```
 var nameget = localStorage.getItem("nams");
```

and appending it to following

```
chatMessages[id].push('<strong>' + nameget + ':   ' + '</strong> ' + value);
```

But now the problem is it is getting fetched only once.

How do i fetch it more then once?

Comment: Hello Ruchya , didnt you get the answer here ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801171/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-localstorage-in-the-order-we-set-it  This is correct and nice Answer

Comment: @PratikJoshi I dont think that is what i need :(

Comment: What do you mean by "more than once"? You can use `localStorage.getItem()` whenever you need to.

Comment: @Richa , Ruchya Juhana is correct , localstorage can be used more than once whenever you need.

Comment: As you can see i am looping it 3 times , fetching data 3 times http://jsfiddle.net/LH2zB/

Comment: @Richa I guess understood the problem. I think a better better description would be "I want to store multiple values entered from a text box in `localStorage` and access it later from another js file…" am i right..?

Answer (score 0):

For storing multiple items, You need to `Stringify` and store an array in `localStorage`

Whenever you want to add new data, retried the value from `localStorage`, `parse` it, push the new data into it and store it back.

Something like the following:

```
name = $('#chat-box-name').val();
// retrieve stored data or create a blank array if there isn't any info saved yet
var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names') || [];
// add to it,
names.push(name);
// then put it back.
localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(names));
```